Running a python script with function imports from a different version
I have a script called "SyncMapF.py" that runs on python 3.7.4, my main script runs on 3.12.2
i need some way to send variables from my main script to SyncMapF.py and have it run.
i've been searching forever and nothing really useful comes up (i probably don't know the terminology yet, im new to python)
p.s both scripts work and im able to run them within VSC code using different interpreters.

Are you saying that your "SyncMapF.py" does not run on 3.12.2 ?  Can't you port it to the 3.12.2? What is the exact issue that you are facing ? What error do you get if you run SyncMapF.py in 3.12.2 ?

SyncMapF.py relies on libraries that cannot be installed on 3.12.2. thus, trying to run it with the main script gives "No module" found errors.

i got no idea how i got it, but using os.system("Python Filepath") actually works and im able to run my 3.7.4 script from within the 3.12.2 script.

os.system is to execute a command (in your case your script) in a subshell. But when you write just "python scriptname" the python has to be your old 3.7.4 otherwise you will face the same issue.
